# server returns 404 when request for specific image comes from ie8

Tags: wordpress, http, cross-browser, http-status-code-404

I have a link to an image that works properly in every browser, but ie8. Extremely strange behavior...

If you click this link in ie8, you'll get a 404, otherwise the image will load...

```
http://www.manateenewjobsnow.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/EDATE_Map.jpg
```

What could possibly be different between ie8 and ie9 that causes a link to 404?

Just looking for a lead here, how could an http request for the same resource give different responses across browsers? How could the browser be a factor in the server's response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That image uses CMYK color model, ,maybe IE8 does not support that. Try changing it to RGB.

Comment: I opened up the image in Fireworks and saved a new copy of it. Uploaded that image and it worked like a charm. I never would have found that myself.